# Determine the derivative of the reciprocal function, only with the product rule.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

1. Following is given:

   $( \alpha )$ the derivative of a inverse function: $$\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)' = -\frac{f'}{f^2}$$

   $( \beta )$ The the product rule: $$({f}*g) = ({f'}*{g})+({f}*{g'})$$
2. Following is asked:

   become $\alpha ,$ by using $\beta .$ starting with: $$f(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right) = {1}$$
3. General information about the function
   If the function f(x) is derivable in the open interval ]a,b[ and f(x) isn't zero in ]a,b[, then is the inverse function $\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)$ derivable in ]a,b[ then applies ( \alpha ) .
4. My solution on (2) 

    starting with: $f(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right) = {1}$ 

   **First:** apply the product rule we become:
   $$f'(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right) + f(x)\left(-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)  = {0}$$ 

   that's the same as: $f'(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right) - f(x)\left(\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)  = {0}$ 

   **Second;** apply the product rule again:
   $$f''(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)+f'(x)\left(-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)-f'(x)\left(\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)+f(x)\left(-\frac{2*1}{f^3(x)}\right)=0$$

   that's the same as:
   $f''(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)-f'(x)\left(\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)-f'(x)\left(\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)-f(x)\left(\frac{2*1}{f^3(x)}\right)=0$

   **Third;** simplify the result: (put equal terms first)
   $$\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)[1-\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)]-\left(\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)[f'(x) - \left(2\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}\right)]$$

   that's the same as:
   $\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)[1-\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)]-\left(\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)[f'(x) - \left(\frac{2}{1}\right)]$

   More simplification ( \beta ): 
   $$\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)-\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}\right)-\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}\right) + \left(\frac{2}{f^2(x)}\right)=0$$

   $$\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)-2\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{f^2(x)}\right)=0$$

   $$\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)-2\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}\right) 
   [1-\left(\frac{1}{f'(x)}\right)] =0$$

    
   **Last**; the solution: 

     Take the *First* and *third* part of the equation. Bring it to the right part.

     We get: 
   $$-2\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}\right) 
   [1] =\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f'(x)f(x)}\right)$$
   That's is the same as: (make it cleaner and use the following identities).

    The identity:$\left(\frac{a^r}{b^r}\right) = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^r$
   $$-2\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)'$$
5. My problem/question 
   How can i get rid of the **2**?
    We can only use the **product rule**.

Comment: what do you mean you want to get rid of $f \times \frac 1 f = 1?$ is that not the definition of $\frac 1 f?$

Comment: ... I meant. To eliminate the "2", in my solution... 2 in -(f'/f^2). (In step 4, last equation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start there is an error, namely:
$$f'(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right) + f(x)\left(-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)  = {0}$$

Instead just write, using the product rule with $g(x)= 1/f(x)$: 
$$f'(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right) + f(x)\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)'  = {0}$$

Now  you have an equation involving $\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)'$.
Just transform the equation to express $\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)'$ in terms of $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your reply. You suggest "Now solve for ...", but isn't that basically what i did? By step 4... First: apply the product rule. Maybe you can just tell what is wrong.

Comment: The point is that you need to pretend *you do not know* what   $\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)' $ is. Let us call it $u(x)$ to make this more clear. So you have $f'(x) (1/f(x)) + f(x)u(x)= 0$. And this yields $u(x) =  -f'(x)/(f(x))^2$, which is what you want.

Comment: Since I submitted the first comment incomletely let me write another: what is wrong is that in the equation is quoted you already use alpha. Thus this can never be a proof of alpha.

Comment: OK. I was confused. You mean, i have to use the "Reciprocal rule". Thanks for helping !

Comment: No. I mean that you did use the reciprocal rule, but in fact must not use the reciprocal rule. How exactly do you get the equation your write after "First:" that I quoted? (Added: perhaps I misunderstood what you mean to say. Put differenly, yes the issue is that you have to use the reciprocal rule to get your "First", and you cannot do this.)

Comment: OK. I thought 1/f(x) equals 1*f^-1(x). Than take the derivative; you become -(1*1)*f^-2 equals -(1*1)/f^2(x). You can see i didn't take the reciprocal, because there is no f'(x) term on it (by first).

Comment: Ah, right. I did not even note that now I understand better. This is quite wrong. If you do it like this you would need to use the chain rule, which would introduce an $f'(x)$. Moroever you use how to differentiate $1/x$ which is a special case of the reciprocal rule.

Comment: Yes i know. the chain rule is not permitted at the moment. thanks for now. and the solution for 1/x is -1/x^2 nothing special about it.